# how to retrieve data from api on java android and use it?

Tags: java, android, api, gson, retrofit2

Hi everybody and thanks for helping me,

I'm trying to fetch data from an api url "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search?order=desc&sort=creation&site=stackoverflow&tagged=android" and I don't know what I am missing.
I keep on getting an error saying that I am pointing to a null object, but it is not supposed to be null.

That is the error message

```
`
        E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.finalhomework, PID: 5005
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.finalhomework.view.SearchActivity$1.onResponse(SearchActivity.java:46)
        at retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1.lambda$onResponse$0$DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1(DefaultCallAdapterFactory.java:89)
        at retrofit2.-$$Lambda$DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$3wC8FyV4pyjrzrYL5U0mlYiviZw.run(lambda)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)`
```

That is the results page which is supposed to get all the item

```
`
        package com.example.finalhomework.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class StackOverflowPageResult implements Serializable
{

    @SerializedName("StackOverflowItem")
    @Expose
    private List<StackOverflowItem> items = null;
    @SerializedName("has_more")
    @Expose
    private Boolean hasMore;
    @SerializedName("quota_max")
    @Expose
    private Integer quotaMax;
    @SerializedName("quota_remaining")
    @Expose
    private Integer quotaRemaining;
    private final static long serialVersionUID = -263378404000205617L;

    public List<StackOverflowItem> getStackOverflowItem() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<StackOverflowItem> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    public Boolean getHasMore() {
        return hasMore;
    }

    public void setHasMore(Boolean hasMore) {
        this.hasMore = hasMore;
    }

    public Integer getQuotaMax() {
        return quotaMax;
    }

    public void setQuotaMax(Integer quotaMax) {
        this.quotaMax = quotaMax;
    }

    public Integer getQuotaRemaining() {
        return quotaRemaining;
    }

    public void setQuotaRemaining(Integer quotaRemaining) {
        this.quotaRemaining = quotaRemaining;
    }

}`
```

That is the Item itself:

```
`
        package com.example.finalhomework.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class StackOverflowItem implements Serializable
{

    @SerializedName("tags")
    @Expose
    private List<String> tags = null;
    @SerializedName("owner")
    @Expose
    private Owner owner;
    @SerializedName("is_answered")
    @Expose
    private Boolean isAnswered;
    @SerializedName("view_count")
    @Expose
    private Integer viewCount;
    @SerializedName("answer_count")
    @Expose
    private Integer answerCount;
    @SerializedName("score")
    @Expose
    private Integer score;
    @SerializedName("last_activity_date")
    @Expose
    private Integer lastActivityDate;
    @SerializedName("creation_date")
    @Expose
    private Integer creationDate;
    @SerializedName("question_id")
    @Expose
    private Integer questionId;
    @SerializedName("content_license")
    @Expose
    private String contentLicense;
    @SerializedName("link")
    @Expose
    private String link;
    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title;
    @SerializedName("last_edit_date")
    @Expose
    private Integer lastEditDate;
    @SerializedName("accepted_answer_id")
    @Expose
    private Integer acceptedAnswerId;
    @SerializedName("closed_date")
    @Expose
    private Integer closedDate;
    @SerializedName("closed_reason")
    @Expose
    private String closedReason;
    private final static long serialVersionUID = 2088551364601451752L;

    public List<String> getTags() {
        return tags;
    }

    public void setTags(List<String> tags) {
        this.tags = tags;
    }

    public Owner getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

    public void setOwner(Owner owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    public Boolean getIsAnswered() {
        return isAnswered;
    }

    public void setIsAnswered(Boolean isAnswered) {
        this.isAnswered = isAnswered;
    }

    public Integer getViewCount() {
        return viewCount;
    }

    public void setViewCount(Integer viewCount) {
        this.viewCount = viewCount;
    }

    public Integer getAnswerCount() {
        return answerCount;
    }

    public void setAnswerCount(Integer answerCount) {
        this.answerCount = answerCount;
    }

    public Integer getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public void setScore(Integer score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

    public Integer getLastActivityDate() {
        return lastActivityDate;
    }

    public void setLastActivityDate(Integer lastActivityDate) {
        this.lastActivityDate = lastActivityDate;
    }

    public Integer getCreationDate() {
        return creationDate;
    }

    public void setCreationDate(Integer creationDate) {
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
    }

    public Integer getQuestionId() {
        return questionId;
    }

    public void setQuestionId(Integer questionId) {
        this.questionId = questionId;
    }

    public String getContentLicense() {
        return contentLicense;
    }

    public void setContentLicense(String contentLicense) {
        this.contentLicense = contentLicense;
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Integer getLastEditDate() {
        return lastEditDate;
    }

    public void setLastEditDate(Integer lastEditDate) {
        this.lastEditDate = lastEditDate;
    }

    public Integer getAcceptedAnswerId() {
        return acceptedAnswerId;
    }

    public void setAcceptedAnswerId(Integer acceptedAnswerId) {
        this.acceptedAnswerId = acceptedAnswerId;
    }

    public Integer getClosedDate() {
        return closedDate;
    }

    public void setClosedDate(Integer closedDate) {
        this.closedDate = closedDate;
    }

    public String getClosedReason() {
        return closedReason;
    }

    public void setClosedReason(String closedReason) {
        this.closedReason = closedReason;
    }

}`
```

That is the Retrofit builder with the url:

```
`
        package com.example.finalhomework.network;

import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class RetrofitInstance {

    private static Retrofit retrofit;
    private static final String BASE_URL ="https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/";

    public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance(){

        if (retrofit == null){

            retrofit = new retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }

        return retrofit;
    }
}`
```

That is the interface with the url's arguments:

```
`
        package com.example.finalhomework.network;

import com.example.finalhomework.model.StackOverflowPageResult;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Query;

public interface GetStackOverflowItemDataService {

    @GET("search")
    Call<StackOverflowPageResult> getStackOverflowItem(
            @Query("tagged") String tagged,
            @Query("site") String site,
            @Query("sort") String sort,
            @Query("order") String order

    );
}`
```

And here we've got the class which is supposed to get the total result, and I put a Log.i in order to check if everything is in order and the **stackOverflowItems** is null:

```
`
        package com.example.finalhomework.view;

import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.example.finalhomework.R;
import com.example.finalhomework.model.StackOverflowItem;
import com.example.finalhomework.model.StackOverflowPageResult;
import com.example.finalhomework.network.GetStackOverflowItemDataService;
import com.example.finalhomework.network.RetrofitInstance;

import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    private GetStackOverflowItemDataService stackOverflowItemDataService;
    List<StackOverflowItem> stackOverflowItems;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

        setToolbarBack();

        stackOverflowItemDataService = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(GetStackOverflowItemDataService.class);
        stackOverflowItemDataService.getStackOverflowItem("android", "stackoverflow", "creation", "desc")
                .enqueue(new Callback<StackOverflowPageResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<StackOverflowPageResult> call, Response<StackOverflowPageResult> response) {

                        StackOverflowPageResult stackOverflowPageResult = response.body();

                        stackOverflowItems = stackOverflowPageResult.getStackOverflowItem();


                        for (StackOverflowItem s : stackOverflowItems) {
                            Log.i("Item StackOverflow :", s.getTitle());
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<StackOverflowPageResult> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                });
    }`
```

Again thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

There is mismatch between JSON data variable and your `@SerializedName("StackOverflowItem")`

[image]

So make the changes to match the SerializedName, code as follows -

```
public class StackOverflowPageResult implements Serializable {
        
    @SerializedName("items")
    private List<StackOverflowItem> items;

    @SerializedName("has_more")
    private Boolean hasMore;

    @SerializedName("quota_max")
    private Integer quotaMax;

    @SerializedName("quota_remaining")
    private Integer quotaRemaining;
    
    // your further code here
    //.............
}
```

SerializedName is only required when you are going to take variable name different from JSON object, otherwise you can skip `@SerializedName` tag as well.

One more thing I suggest, I you are not going to call `excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()` in your **GsonBuilder** class, then there is no need for @Expose tag.

The Gson @Expose annotation can be used to mark a field to be exposed or not (included or not) for serialized or deserialized. The @Expose annotation can take two parameters and each parameter is a boolean which can take either the value true or false. In order to get GSON to react to the @Expose annotations we must create a Gson instance using the GsonBuilder class and need to call the excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation() method, it configures Gson to exclude all fields from consideration for serialization or deserialization that do not have the Expose annotation.

Happy Coding !